Counit map surjective
Let $X \to Y$ a (set theoretically) surjective morphism of schemes, $L$ a line bundle/invertible sheaf on $X$ (maybe more generally a locally free coh sheaf, but let's stick firstly on invertible sheaf) and $c: f^*f_*L \to L$ the counit map.
Question: When $c$ is surjective, if we explicitly exclude the case where $f$ is affine (...there the statement would be trivial as one can reduce to local always surj map $M_{\vert A} \otimes_A B \to M$)?
Rmk: This is essentially "dual" of this and "double dual" of this one, but here I want explicitly exclude the boring affine case.
More precisely, this question is originally inspired by the argumentation in the proof of Thm. 5.3 (p 48) in these notes by Debarre on Mori theory.
[There the context there was rather specific: $Y=B$ was a smooth curve over alg closed field $k$, $X$ a surface, $L=O_X(C)$ comes from divisor $C \subset X$, $E:=f_*L$ is locally free and every fibre $X_b$ of $f$ is line $\cong \Bbb P^1_k$ with $L_{ \vert X_b} \cong O_{\Bbb P^1}(1)$
(...but think $O_{\Bbb P^1}(n), n >0$ would still not destroy the argument)
Then the script claims that the counit $c: f^*f_*L \to L$ is surjective.
The argumentation there goes as follows: Firstly by Nakayama argument it suffice to restrict to fibers, then as by assumption $L$ restrict on fibres to $O_{P^1}(1)$, which is very ample, so globally generated, ie canon map
$$ H^0(\Bbb P^1, O_{\Bbb P^1}(1)) \otimes O_{\Bbb P^1} \to O_{\Bbb P^1}(1) $$
is surjective, it suffice to check that the induced map
$$ i_b^*f^*f_*L = f_*L \otimes \kappa(b) \to H^0(\Bbb P^1, O_{\Bbb P^1}(1))   $$
(where $i_b: X_b \to X$ canon inclusion of fibre $X_b$, $b \in B$) is surjective. This comes from a semicontinuity argument, see eg Hartshorne, Chap III, 12 for details.]
So here it seems highly depend on ampleness of $L$ restricted to fibres. How far this argument can be generalized and adapted to initial question above on surjectivity of counit map $c$.
Moreover, are there more "standard cases" when the counit map must be always surjective.

In the case $Y = \operatorname{Spec} k$, this means that $\mathscr L$ is globally generated. So this is a relative version of global generation. It certainly holds when $\mathscr L$ is $f$-very ample [Tag 01VR], even without flatness (which is used in the argument you quoted). It will be a subtle question in general. (Note that very ample sheaves are globally generated, but ample sheaves not necessarily; see for instance this answer.)
